# How do I get passed the error "infiniteScroll is not a function"?

Tags: php, jquery, html, css

I've followed a number of tutorials to get Masonry working with Infinite Scroll, but I keep coming across the error "infiniteScroll is not a function".

I've initially been looking at this documentation... https://masonry.desandro.com/v2/docs/methods.html#appended
Along with this example...
https://masonry.desandro.com/v2/demos/infinite-scroll.html

Both the links above relate to an old version and directed me to...
https://masonry.desandro.com/
This doesn't appear to have any Masonry / Infinite Scroll Examples using a current version.

I've found a Masonry section on the Infinite Scroll site...
https://infinite-scroll.com/#masonry-isotope-packery
This led me to the following example...
https://codepen.io/desandro/pen/eRRQVo

I've been reading through this post...
https://github.com/desandro/masonry/issues/747
desandro commented on 28 Aug 2015...
"Years ago, I would recommend Infinite Scroll but it's no longer supported, so beware."
rugor commented on 5 Sep 2015...
"Alternatively, Infinite Ajax Scroll works like a treat."
desandro commented on 12 Sep 2017...
"Infinite Scroll v3 has been released with a brand new rewrite including tight Masonry support. Please try upgrading to the Infinite Scroll v3."
I'm assuming I'm OK to keep tackling this with the latest versions of Masonry and Infinite Scroll or should I be going down the "Infinite Ajax Scroll" route?

I've also looked at this...
https://potentpages.com/web-design/infinite-scroll/tutorials/masonry

**HEAD CODE**

```
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script src="https://unpkg.com/infinite-scroll@3/dist/infinite-scroll.pkgd.js"></script>
    <script src="https://unpkg.com/masonry-layout@4/dist/masonry.pkgd.js"></script>
```

**TEMPLATE CODE**

```
<div class="grid">
    <div class="grid-sizer"></div>
    <div class="gutter-sizer"></div>
    <?php $paged = (get_query_var('paged')) ? get_query_var('paged') : 1;
    $args = array( 'post_type' => 'post', 'posts_per_page' => 10, 'paged' => $paged );
    $wp_query = new WP_Query($args);
    while ( have_posts() ) : the_post(); ?>
        <div class="grid-item">
            <?php if ( has_post_thumbnail() ) : ?>
                <a class="featured" href="<?php the_permalink(); ?>" title="<?php the_title_attribute(); ?>">
                    <?php the_post_thumbnail(); ?>
                </a>
            <?php endif; ?>
            <h3><a href="<?php the_permalink(); ?>"><?php the_title(); ?></a></h3>
            <?php the_excerpt(); ?>
        </div>
    <?php endwhile; ?>
</div> <!-- grid -->
<div class="page-load-status">
    <div class="loader-ellips infinite-scroll-request">
        <span class="loader-ellips__dot"></span>
        <span class="loader-ellips__dot"></span>
        <span class="loader-ellips__dot"></span>
        <span class="loader-ellips__dot"></span>
    </div>
    <p class="infinite-scroll-last">End of content</p>
    <p class="infinite-scroll-error">No more pages to load</p>
</div>
<div class="pagination">
    <?php next_posts_link( '&larr; Older posts', $wp_query ->max_num_pages); ?>
    <?php previous_posts_link( 'Newer posts &rarr;' ); ?>
</div> <!-- pagination -->
```

**JS**

```
jQuery(document).ready(function($) {

        "use strict";

        $(function() {

            //-------------------------------------//
            // init Masonry

            var $grid = $('.grid').masonry({
                itemSelector: 'none', // select none at first
                columnWidth: '.grid-sizer',
                gutter: '.gutter-sizer',
                percentPosition: true,
                stagger: 30,
                // nicer reveal transition
                visibleStyle: { transform: 'translateY(0)', opacity: 1 },
                hiddenStyle: { transform: 'translateY(100px)', opacity: 0 },
            });

            // get Masonry instance
            var msnry = $grid.data('masonry');

            // initial items reveal
            $grid.imagesLoaded( function() {
                $grid.removeClass('are-images-unloaded');
                $grid.masonry( 'option', { itemSelector: '.grid-item' });
                var $items = $grid.find('.grid-item');
                $grid.masonry( 'appended', $items );
            });

            //-------------------------------------//
            // init Infinte Scroll

            $grid.infiniteScroll({
                path: '.nextPosts',
                append: '.grid-item',
                outlayer: msnry,
                status: '.page-load-status',
            });

        });


    }); /* End Document Ready */
```

**FUNCTIONS CODE**

```
/************* Add Pagination Class ********************/

add_filter('next_posts_link_attributes', 'next_posts_link_attributes');

function next_posts_link_attributes() {
    return 'class="nextPosts"';
}
```

I get the following error...
"$grid.infiniteScroll is not a function"
I get the same error with other tutorials.

It seems my issue is more to do with the error "infiniteScroll is not a function" and nothing to do with the tutorial I try and follow.
Responses to other people with this issue have been...
"You should make sure your initialization code is inside a $(function(){}), because you need the DOM to be ready before running infinitescroll."
OR 
"Make sure you've included the infinite scroll package."
I've tried/checked both of these suggestions.

Any help to get past this error would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: This is a wordpress site, so these scripts are not registered properly. You should use the enqueue scripts filter to add them. This way they are appended AFTER wordpress's specific version of jQuery.

Comment: Many thanks Deckerz for taking the time to read my post... You've solved my problem and made my day!

Simple when you know how...